# yii2-admin. Как задать роут для админки?

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь разобраться с этой [админкой](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)
Использую шаблон advanced. 
Интересует вопрос. Как указать route на backend?

Answer (score 0):

Что вы имеет под указать route? в методе url route?

если вы имеете ввиду urlmanager и пути, то когда вы подключаете модуль - вы пишите под каким названием он будет доступен.
если вы его подключаете в backend config к примеру baseUrl там будет = backend, а модуль установлен с названием admin / то путь будет backend/admin

под именем модуля я имею ввиду алиас который указывается :

```
return [
    ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@mdm/admin' => 'path/to/your/extracted',
        // for example: '@mdm/admin' => '@app/extensions/mdm/yii2-admin-2.0.0',
        ...
    ]
```